# Openstack in hosted environment

Tags: networking, cloud, openstack, grizzly, openstack-neutron

I am trying to configure OpenStack in a hosted environment where I don't have access to network equipment. That's why I want to use GRE tunnels to create an internal OpenStack network.

**The environment**

The host is Softlayer where the servers provided have access to two different networks.
One is a private network (a bonded interface, bond0) and the second is a public network (another bonded interface, bond1).

Public interfaces have publicly accessible IP addresses. There is also the possibility to have public portable IP addresses routed to public network (accessible through the bond1 interface).

The private network is based on one customer VLAN. There are multiple subnets sitting inside this VLAN. Each subnet has a gateway managed by Softlayer.

**The requirements**

I would like to achieve similar setting as described in this [Cisco document](http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/COE_Grizzly_Release:_High-Availability_Manual_Installation_Guide)
but using GRE tunnels.

I would like my VMs to access non-openstack resources. I would like them to have floating IPs assigned as needed. I would like to do it with quantum from grizzly release to be able to have highly-available network nodes (l3-agent have this option starting with grizzly release).

**Questions**

1. Should br-int be bond0 and br-ex be bond1?
2. Should I use completely new subnets for VMs (like 172.16.0.0/16) outside Softlayer private subnets (10.0.0.0/8) and treat SL subnets as external?
3. Can I use SL subnets for my VMs? How would I achieve that? How should I configure OpenStack router to route between VMs and real network? Let's say I order network 10.20.30.0/26 from Softlayer. It has a gateway with IP address 10.20.30.1. I want to give my VMs addresses .2, .3 and so on, but how to route them into OpenStack and back?
4. How would you recommend I configure a network in such environment?